# How do I clone a Class::Struct?

Tags: perl, clone

I have a hash of [`Class::Struct`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct), how do I clone it (deep copy)? [`Class::Struct`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct) does not provide a `clone` or `copy` method and manually copying the internals of [`Class::Struct`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct) would be hard.

```
my %a = ();

$a{k} = MyStruct->new;

my %b = ... ?
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) module provides a `dclone` function that is able to deep-copy the hash and the [`Class::Struct`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct) contents.

```
use Storable qw/dclone/;

my %a = ();
$a{k} = MyStruct->new;

my %b =  %{dclone(\%a)};
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!